# jquery qtip plugin

Tags: jquery, qtip

I am using the jQuery qTip plugin and am having trouble loading html content into it from another element.

I have the following code:

```
$('.tip').qtip({
    content: { 
        text: $(this).next('.product_info').html() 
    }
});
```

with the following html:

```
<a href="#" class="tip">An Image</a>
<div class="product_info">Some content</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to use "$(this)" so how can I refer to the current ".tip"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this question's answer will answer this for you:
[qtip jquery plugin to display text from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290685/qtip-jquery-plugin-to-display-text-from-link)

basically you need to loop through your things to tip and then tip then individually and this will work;

```
$('.tip').each(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content: { 
            text: $(this).next('.product_info').html() 
        }
     });
});
```